# How to read only some of the files from the same folder in r studio?

Tags: r

I have a folder with multiple files and I would like to import to R Studio only the files with specific code in the name of the file.

Comment: `dir()` to get the files in the directory, `grepl` to check if the name of the file contains "specific code" and then `lapply` or `sapply` or whatever your favorite way to loop to read in the files

Comment: `files_to_read <- list.files(path = "your/directory/", pattern = "regex for your specific code in the name of the file")`. The regex can just be the literal pattern if it doesn't include special characters for regex and doesn't occur in other files in the directory.